# How can i do pinch and drag uiview?

Tags: iphone, uitouch

How can i do pinch and drag uiview ?
i need functionality as used in google maps (drag and move and pinch gestures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a UIScrollView instead.

Comment: Yes.  It uses an MKMapView, which if you want to show a map, may be even better.